# Branch current method for a given circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Could somebody check if I did the branch current method correctly on the given circuit immediately after the switch has been closed? See the circuit in Figure 1.1 in the image below.

My solution consists of the three equations 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that i3 goes to 0 as t goes to infinity, and that i2 goes to -i1? Have you calculated i1 and i2 at t=infinity using Ohm's Law? You can do a lot to check your own work here.

Comment: Hello @ElliotAlderson thanks a lot for your comment. Please note that u_q(t) is in general not constant. This voltage supply could be a sinuswave for instance or something else. I do not definded here a specific voltage supply. Are the three equations correct? BR Marco

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a 2 equations system for it's resolution:
With branch current method in a circuit like that you can choose just 2 equations, one with I1 and other with I2 and, when you have in both equations the R2 terms written like a subtract of one current minus the other.
In that case you would end up with just 2 equations and 2 unknowns.

Appart of that advise, I end up with similar equations by my method so I hope It's allright, but I encourage You to use the other method for easier understanding and future resolution with given values.

Comment: Dear @Charlython, thank you so much for your answer. I'm highly interested in your solution (you wrote: "I end up with similar equations by my method so I hope It's allright"). Could you maybe post it here (screenshot or picture)? Of course, later I do it like you recommended to me (you wrote: "2 equations system"). Your idea looks very interesting. THX and BR Marco